# Side Noise in Alfa Romeo 159 when driving +100 km/h?

Tags: noise, alfa-romeo

I am investigating a car which seems perfect when speed less than 100 km/h. When driven more than 100 km/h, there is a side noise somewhere, but I have no idea where it comes and how. Everything has been checked 12/2016, next time 12/2017. 
Very nice piece othertise, driven 170 000 km, no accidents, nice bottom of the car - - no damages.

Side noise: I hear a continuous side noise (from the right side) which comes you drive faster than 100 km/h. I does not come from tires, because tested with other set. I do not see any leakages in the motor. 
There is no noise when you drive less than 100 km/h.

- I think the noise is not like the one in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLz-zeKGW-U) coming from the right headlight, but exclude it completely. I cannot understand why the side noise occurs at the higher speed only - - maybe because vibration only then significant.

Which typical effects can cause a side noise when driving 100 km/h?

Car: Alfa Romeo 159 1.9 JTS 4d
Fuel: bensin
Kilometers: 170 000
Manufactured: 2007

Comment: Does the noise change pitch if you go through a corner or change lanes (at speed)?

Comment: I think it does not change when I change a lane.

Comment: I am not sure what "side noise" is, other than the sound you hear from one side of the car. Anyway, is it possible this could be the sound of air passing through an open seal; similar to if the window were open slightly? The faster you drive, the louder the air noise it passing over the gap.

Comment: @CharlieRB I checked the windows but nothing there that could explain it.

Comment: Unless you can give us more information about what "side noise" is, we are just grasping in the dark. Has this car always made this sound? Or is this something new? I have driven some cars that have design flaws that cause aerodynamic noise. One was how the air transitioned from the hood to the windshield caused a "whooshing" sound at highway speed. The other was an antenna design that whistled in the wind. They had to make an aerodynamic cover to eliminate the noise.

Comment: @CharlieRB No, it has not made the noise always.

Comment: Isolate the location the sound is coming from and get a recording of it? Maybe if we know a location and can hear it, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question, but as I had it myself on my 159 and on my new Giulia as well...
It is most likely wind-noise coming through the weather-seals at the top of one of the doors.
Only noticeable when driving fast enough and (in some cases) may go away when driving even faster.

You can verify this by pressing some fingers into various spots on the weather-strip while driving and listen if the sound changes. (Obviously have a passenger do that for any door which is not the drivers door !)
My 159 had it on the rear-door passenger-side and my Giulia has it (less pronounced) on the driver-side front-door.

On my 159 (which I bought 2nd hand and which was out of warranty) I was able to fix it myself by prying open the weather-strip and packing a thin strip of extra rubber under it to bulk it up, improving the seal. (An old piece of rubber hose which I cut length-wise to get a strip.)
This cured the problem completely.

My Giulia is still under factory warranty so I'm not going to mess with it myself.
It will get its scheduled 60.000 KM service next Monday. I'll be checking with the workshop if they can do something about the noise.